# Remove formatting in rich text with Gutenbergs Block editor

Tags: block-editor, formatting, workflow

In the classic editor, an option for removing all formatting in a selected text was possible in the visual tab.

Is there such a function for Gutenberg? 
If not, is it planned at some point?

What would be the easiest workflow for establishing a 'clear all tags and links' procedure in your opinion with Gutenberg without such an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such function in there yet.

You can find this bug: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8869 and it's still open as enhancement.

On the other hand, you can paste using Cmd+Shift+V (Ctrl+Shift+V on Win) and it should paste your text ignoring most of formatting, I guess.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as answered until the issue develops further with enhancements like the linked 'bug'.